# pivot point for guitar's strap

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints

[image: object with transform origin data displayed]
basically i want to add a bone to my rigify rig which take the location data from this strap in the center, (particularly the rotation, and location) so that it can smoothly rotate around the torso with like r -> z. the next step will be adding bones in the guitar's neck to latch on to the player's hands during animations. This is the plan as it stands and I'm not sure how copy transform data between object and bone since a bone has the two ends? But would this seem like the approach you would take for this? any help is appreciated :) this is also gonna be for a game

Comment: Please add your image into your question rather than just adding a link to it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: hey i just fixed it

Comment: Thanks. You're more likely to get answers if folks can see immediately what you're talking about rather than having to click a link to see your image.

Comment: does this forum have that issue like reddit where your post is supposed to get seen at the beginning? Should i consider reposting so it can be seen?

Comment: No, topics are sorted by latest activity by default. Do not repost anything ever here. Make your topic better by editing, or comment, that's plenty enough. The best way to have an answer is to have the best topic quality as possible anyway.

Comment: Rigging a prop so to have multiple anchor points for it can be a little tricky to do (and also to animate). Often the chosen solution is to just have one bone that will be dynamically parented to any other controller the animator wants (for example you can use multiple Child Of constraints that target either a hand bone, or chest, etc). and another bone as child, which is the actual parent of the prop. that way you can animate the offset, as well as which parent to follow using the constraints factors. Then you constrain the other hand to the prop with a similar system.

Comment: Another approach could be to have your prop parented to the chest or the hip, not the hands, and instead add anchor bones parented to the prop, which each a child offset bone for each hand's main IK controllers to be child of via constraints. That way, you position the hands as you wish on the guitar, enable their parenting to the anchor points, and then you can animate the guitar : the hands will follow, or move the anchor points and the hands around their anchors. This would allow for example to have an anchor point aligned with the handle, making slides really easy to do.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the answer. More of a concern is movement of the body and guitar 'as a weapon' since it's an action game. the type of things are swinging the neck out ahead as attack. A video I saw recommended duplicating the hand bone and having an identical one parented to the object which i could put on the neck. Another character I made used bones which u can click together to for example move and rotate a head with a helmet that's detachable. The reason my pose asked about the transform position of the strap is because the loop would move with the guitar for action poses.